# Tidy HTML and Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi

I am trying to use tidy lib to clean up html code stored in a database.
I have tried both TidyPas and diTidy to accomplish this, but I keep getting an access violation, regardless of what I use - it blows up on the parseString.
Can anyone help or have suggestions of things to try?

this is my function(using diTidy), but TidyPas gets same results:

```
 procedure tdmSME.TidyHTML(aField : tField);
var
  aString : String;
  nString : AnsiString;
  ResultCode:LongInt;
  TidyHandle: TidyDoc;
  Target: TidyBuffer;
  ErrorBuffer: TidyBuffer;
begin
   aString := rxStrUtils.replaceStr(aField.AsString, #10, ' ');
   aString := rxStrUtils.replaceStr(aString, #13, '');
   nString := AnsiString(aString);
   TidyHandle := tidyCreate;
   tidyOptSetBool(TidyHandle, TidyMark, 0);
   tidyOptSetInt(TidyHandle, TidyDocTypeMode, 1);
   tidyOptSetBool(TidyHandle, TidyHTMLOut, 1);
   tidyOptSetBool(TidyHandle, TidyMakeClean,1);
   tidyOptSetBool(TidyHandle, TidyDropFontTags, 1);

   ResultCode := tidySetErrorBuffer(TidyHandle, @ErrorBuffer);
   try
      try
         if ResultCode >= 0 then
            ResultCode := tidyParseString(TidyHandle, pAnsiChar(nString));----Access violation
         if ResultCode >= 0 then
            ResultCode := tidyCleanAndRepair(TidyHandle);
         if ResultCode >= 0 then
            ResultCode := tidyRunDiagnostics(TidyHandle);
         if ResultCode >= 1 then
           tidyOptSetBool(TidyHandle, TidyForceOutput, 1);
         TidyBufInit(@Target);
         if ResultCode >= 0 then
            ResultCode := tidySaveBuffer(TidyHandle, @Target);
         if ResultCode >= 0 then
         begin
//            if ResultCode > 0 then // Warnings?
//            begin
//               ShowMessage(PAnsiChar(ErrorBuffer.bp));
//            end;
            aField.AsString := string(Target.bp);
         end
         else
            ShowMessage('A severe error (' +  intToStr(ResultCode) + ') occurred: ');
      except
        on E:Exception do
           ShowMessage('Some Error occurred on ' + aString + ':' + E.Message);
      end;
   finally
         tidyBufFree(@Target);
         tidyBufFree(@ErrorBuffer);
         tidyRelease(TidyHandle);
   end;
end;
```

Comment: Have you tested thet nString is not empty? Because if that's the case then  pAnsiChar(nString) becomes nil and might result in an AV

Comment: nString is not empty,   it has html value in it.